# How do I change FROM address using mailx on FreeBSD from command line?

Tags: command-line, freebsd, email, mailx

I'm using following system:

```
$ uname -a
FreeBSD X 9.2-RELEASE-p17 FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p17 #0 r282430: Mon May  4 13:59:58 PDT 2015     root@X:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/R610  amd64
$ pkg info mailx
mailx-0.5_1
Name           : mailx
Version        : 0.5_1
Installed on   : Fri May 15 11:16:36 2015 EDT
Origin         : mail/mailx
Architecture   : freebsd:9:x86:64
Prefix         : /usr/local
Categories     : mail
Licenses       : 
Maintainer     : ports@FreeBSD.org
WWW            : UNKNOWN
Comment        : Mail command with mailx extensions
Annotations    :
    repo_type      : binary
    repository     : FreeBSD
Flat size      : 104KiB
Description    :
Mail command with mailx extensions.

    Mailx command is based on BSD mail command, but it also provides some
enhanced features such as:

o Edit header information.
o Use pager program to display long message.
o Add pipe (|) command.  You can pass the mail message to the shell command by
  using this feature.
o Add Save, Copy command.
o Add askcc, askbcc command.  The mailx program ask you Cc: and Bcc: at the
  beggining.
o Add hsubject command.  This is similar to subject command, but it only
  displays Subject: headers.
o Add tilda escape command.

See also the files in ${PREFIX}/share/doc/mailx directory.
$
```

How do I change FROM address using `mailx` on `FreeBSD` from command line?

Answer (score 2):

FreeBSD (the OS) does not have a mailx program. There are however several programs called mailx which is derived from Berkeley Mail. Some are ported to FreeBSD and are available as packages.

The OP is using the package:
[mailx-0.5_1](http://www.freshports.org/mail/mailx/)

This package is a fairly old Perl script.

I would rather recommend using the Heirloom version of mailx:
[heirloom-mailx-12.4_7](http://www.freshports.org/mail/heirloom-mailx/)

Though still old - it is much more feature rich. And as @Peschke correctly states: It has the "-r" option which allow you to set the FROM address.

```
mailx -r example@address.com ...
```

See the Heirloom [project page](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html) and [man page](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx/mailx.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if FreeBSD's `mailx` program has this option (I did not see it in their [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mailx&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.3-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html)), but on the GNU/Linux version of `mailx` you use `-r`.

`mailx -r example@address.com ...`

My suggestion would be to use `sendmail`. FreeBSD's `sendmail` program can change the from address with the `-f` argument. Here is the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sendmail&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.3-RELEASE%20and%20Ports).

`sendmail -f "example@address.com" ...`

Comment: `mail(x)?` does _NOT_ have `-r` option - `mail: illegal option -- r`.

Comment: @alexus: I do not think FreeBSD's `mailx` program allows you to change the FROM address. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @peschke: FreeBSD does not ship with mailx. It is added as a 3rd party package. So your answer using "-r" is correct when using the correct package.

Comment: Though old, FreeBSD's `mailx` does *not* have `-r`, but sendmail documents `-r` as obsoleted by `-f` and `mailx` accepts `sendmail` args as well. Note that if your account is not on the trusted users sendmail will add a warning header to each message.